Average cpu MHz via bash and conky
I've been using conky to gather, and display my Linux system stats for a long time. I noticed over a decade ago that the 'average' cpu MHz just copies the first core, it isn't an average of all cores. The command to get the average cpu frequency in conky is: ${freq_g 0}. To get the cores individually, you just use ${freq_g 1} - ${freq_g 12}.
In other words, 0 is supposed to be the average, not the first core, and individually, you start counting at 1, through how many cores you have. But 0 and 1 both always display the exact same thing.
Checking in bash, I run this command:
grep "cpu MHz" </proc/cpuinfo

To get the averge,
grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{sum+=$4;} END{printf "%2.2f", (sum/12)/1000;}'

Now, this works, and it does indeed display the average of the twelve lines that the grep command outputs. And of course the average isn't the same as the first core.
Okay, so far, so good. But we have a problem: I also use a program called corectrl to control the cpu governor, and control the gpu.
When I set the cpu to 'performance mode', the frequency of the cpu jumps up accordingly - from the low 2 GHz range, to the low 4 GHz range, as reported by conky. But when I check the output with the above grep command, all the cores are showing that they're running in the low to mid 3 GHz range.
I'm not really expecting precision numbers here, just pretty close ballpark numbers. Or, in other words, I expect precision numbers, but they're going to change so many time per second that I expect them to be reported differently.
The biggest problem I'm having is that my grep command rarely shows the cpu frequency going above 4 GHz, while conky rarely shows it below 4 GHz - in performance mode. Should I just display the outputs from my grep command in conky, and just accept the two outputs aren't going to jive?

I'm having a very similar issue with conky's built in cpu temperature detection. I can display what conky's builtin is reporting, and the results using sensors, and hwmon. The conky builtin is almost always showing the lowest temperature. The other two methods bounce around a lot more, and usually show higher temperatures then conky's builtin. And I mean they might show a ten degree difference, or more, for a long time.
